# Two applications using the same HTTPS port?

Tags: networking, tcp, process, ip, port

I read somewhere that two different applications/processes cant use the same port at the same time.Suppose i have facebook open on one of my tabs in the browser and youtube playing a video on another tab simultaneously. both use HTTPS. which would make them use port 443, again i have just one internet connection to this device , which means one IP. This is contradictory to what i read, how can youtube and facebook use the same port on the same device at the same time? pardon me if my doubt is silly but it is what it is.

Chatgpt gave me funny answers, and this is my first question on stackoverflow, i want members of the great human race to answer this silly doubt

Comment: Two processes cannot *bind* to the same local port at the same time unless the sockets are bound to different IP addresses and neither of them is `INADDR_ANY`. This is a fair way away from "can't use the same port at the same time".

Answer (score 2):

> I read somewhere that two different applications/processes cant use the same port at the same time.

I'm not sure where you read that or what was meant by it, but it's not true. Without seeing the reference, it's not possible to explain what it was trying to say, but it's not even close to true at all.

For example:

1. A server can bind to a particular port and then share its listening socket with another server. Both servers can now accept connections to that port. (Though not commonly done, there are usually platform-specific ways to control which connections go to which server(s).)
2. A server can bind to a particular port with a particular local IP address and then another server can bind to that same port with a different IP address.
3. An application can connect outward to a particular port and additional local applications can connect out to that same port with either the same remote IP address or different remote IP addresses.

What is true is:

1. Every TCP connection that exists at a particular time for a given machine must differ in either local IP address, remote IP address, local port, or remote port. All four cannot be the same.
2. Most TCP implementations will not allow two processes to bind distinct sockets to the same local port unless they bind to different local IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

It applies on the serverside(youtube.com / facebook.com) not on clientside (your device/browser).You can browse any number of sites clientside.That is nothing to do with `same port rule`